# MySQL, phpMyAdmin: after insert trigger not firing

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have defined the following trigger on my database in phpMyAdmin:
[image]

It's a very simple trigger where I just insert a record into the *history* table after an insert in the *item* table:

```
insert into history values(null, new.Id, new.LocationId, new.LocationId, new.PersonId, new.PersonId, date(now()))
```

However, the trigger is not firing (and it worked correctly when I tested it in MySQL Workbench).

**Edit 1:**

The trigger fires when I define it with some dummy values, like this:

```
insert into history values(null, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, date(now()))
```

**Edit 2:**

The *history* table is written into when I define the trigger with dummy values (see edit 1). But the most recently added entry's ID is 11 (ID is auto_increment), even though the last entry before that had ID = 3. My point is that they are not consecutive, but rather as if there were entries in between but were deleted for some reason...

**Edit 3:**

Here is the DDL for *item* and *history* tables:

```
create table Item
(
Id int not null auto_increment primary key,
InventoryNumber int not null unique,
ItemStatus varchar(20) not null,
ItemType varchar(30) not null,
ItemName varchar(100) not null,
PurchaseDate date not null,
PurchaseValue decimal(12,4) not null,
Amortization decimal(12,4) not null,
LocationId int not null,
PersonId int not null,
foreign key(PersonId) references Person(Id),
foreign key(LocationId) references Location(Id)
);

create table History
(
Id int not null auto_increment primary key,
ItemId int not null,
OldLocationId int not null,
NewLocationId int not null,
OldPersonId int not null,
NewPersonId int not null,
DateOfChange date not null,
foreign key(ItemId) references Item(Id),
foreign key(OldLocationId) references Location(Id),
foreign key(NewLocationId) references Location(Id), 
foreign key(OldPersonId) references Person(Id),
foreign key(NewPersonId) references Person(Id)
);
```

and the trigger (which I think is irrelevant since I didn't import the trigger via a script, I defined it using phpMyAdmin's GUI):

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER historyTriggerInsert AFTER INSERT ON Item
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
insert into History values(null, new.Id, new.LocationId, new.LocationId, new.PersonId, new.PersonId, date(now()));
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

And here is another thing I found out: when I add an entry to *item* using my Yii web application, the entry is visible in the *item* table in phpMA, but the trigger inserts nothing into the *history* table. However, when I add an entry to *item* directly in phpMA, the trigger also creates an entry in *history* i.e. it works correctly.

Also, when I define the trigger with those dummy values but only leave `new.Id`, like this:

```
insert into history values(null, new.Id, 1, 1, 1, 1, date(now()))
```

it also doesn't work. This and the incrementing ID leads me to a conclusion that the trigger is fired, tries to insert into *history*, but for some reason gets an invalid `new.Id` value.

Comment: It's always better (IMHO) to list the columns in an insert, just makes it clear whats going into what.

Comment: @NigelRen Good point, but makes no difference :)

Comment: Check if you are changing the order of your values into the parenthesis. Try setting it with the columns defined at first. `insert into history (Id, LocationId, LocationId, PersonId, PersonId, date) values(new.Id, new.LocationId, new.LocationId, new.PersonId, new.PersonId, date(now()))`. Some of the columns names should be adjusted of course. Also the Id column, as it is autoIncrement as I understand, it can be removed from your insert query, and the null too.

Comment: @VassilikiM. I tried doing that, still not working...

Comment: Answering to your 2nd edit, the reason you are seeing higher IDs is because your query traverses through multiple rows (creating auto_increment primary keys) until inserting your final row. There is a setting in order to lock your auto_increment as needed. Check the following link [AUTO_INCREMENT Handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-configurable)

Comment: Can you run a script to add the trigger instead of using the trigger UI?

Comment: Can you provide the DDL for this? Table creation scripts, as well as trigger creation script. If you don't know what that is, you can probably export the database (backup) to SQL file, and just search through the scripts for the 2 tables and the trigger.

Incrementing ID probably means that it tried to allocate an ID, but failed to insert the record for some reason, failing as a result. So maybe it's a type mismatch or some constraint that we're not aware of.

Comment: @AlexanderMP I've added some new info.

Comment: Try to remove the foreign key from `ItemId`. It looks like the trigger is executing before it can verify the validity of the reference. It wouldn't make sense to have that foreign key anyway, since it would impede deletion of items without you actually deleting the history first, which kinda makes one lose the point in history.

Comment: @AlexanderMP Did it, still doesn't work.

Comment: What are you trying to insert into `Item`?